# Dinamically bind 'format' attribute in wijmo widget using Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, wijmo

In an app we're building using Wijmo and Angular2 one of the requirements is related to the handling of floating-point numbers with different precission. Since the number of digits behind the decimal point may change, we tried to bind the 'format' attribute of the wj-input-number widget to the property DataFormat that we've obtained from the object that our servers returns. Example:

`<wj-input-number [attr.id]='inpProp.Name' [attr.format]='inpProp.DataFormat' class="form-control" [(value)]='inpProp.DoubleValue'></wj-input-number>`

The following method is executed inside the ngAfterViewInit() method of our component, in order to attach the precission of each input to the 'format attribute'

```
addPrecissionProperties(inputGroup:InputGroup) {
    for (let group of inputGroup.InputProperties) {
        if (group.Type == "double") {
            group.DataFormat = 'F' + group.Precision;
        }
    }
}
```

While the hard-coded version works fine, with a code example like the one below running smoothly, we're having trouble binding the 'format' attribute dinamically, and we already checked that we're not in front of a syntax issue regarding Angular2.

`<wj-input-number [attr.id]='inpProp.Name' [attr.format]='F5' class="form-control" [(value)]='inpProp.DoubleValue'></wj-input-number>`

Anyone knows why it doesn't behave dinamically as it should? Any help would be very appreciated.